# Redirect 301 url

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, redirect

I've this url from my website :

```
/portfolio/site-en/www.site.en
```

I want to redirect this url to :

```
/my-work/
```

So in my `.htaccess` file I wrote this :

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /portfolio/site-en/www.site.en /my-work/
```

But it does not work.

Comment: What doesn't work and Where is your .htaccess kept?

Answer (score 0):

You should use RewriteRule instead of Redirect.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^portfolio/site-en/www.site.en /my-work [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.  In particular, why should one choose rewrite over redirect?  And what are the implications on proxy caches?